# PersistChildren Custom Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I've downloaded the AMF framework (Application Mobile Framework) to develop easily a mobile application .NET and the jQuery UI mobile.

I have the following html structure:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LandingPage.ascx.cs" Inherits="mobile.LandingPage" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mob" Namespace="Mobile.WebControls" Assembly="AMF" %>
 <mob:MobilePage Id="mobilePage" Theme="H" runat="server">
 <Header>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="testLabel"></asp:Label>
 </Header>
 <Content>
     <p>
         Welcome in Asp.net Mobile Framework (AMF): The Web Framework for make Web      Application. For Smartphones & Tablets.
     </p>
 </Content>
</mob:MobilePage>
```

But when I want to set the testLabel in the code-behind file I get a nullReferenceException in C#.

The first part of the code of the class from MobilePage in the AMF.dll looks the following

```
[ParseChildren(ChildrenAsProperties = true, DefaultProperty = "Items")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:MobilePage runat=server></{0}:MobilePage>")]
public class MobilePage : Div
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public ArrayList Items
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I have also tried to set ParseChildren to false and to remove the DefaultProperty. In the code behind I have also tried the following:

```
 testLabel = new Label() { Text="hello"};
```

This prevents the nullReferenceException but I didn't see any text.

Does anyone have a solution/suggestion for this problem?

I am using C#3.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: testLabel = new Label() { Text="hello"}; instantiates a new label, not update the UI.  MobilePage is in a DLL you can't correct, right?  I didn't understand when you said you tried to set ParseChildren to false.  What did you apply that too?

Comment: MobilePage is in a DDL that I can correct, because I found the source and changed that a bit to try to solve this problem (including changing the ParseChildren to false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a whole day of searching I've found that the AMF framework don't support view state and form controls:

“In AMF, we can have many mobile page in one asp.net page. We don’t use form control () because we can have multiple form in the same asp.net page. So, standard webcontrol don’t work. We don’t use Viewstate too.”

The following code works well in the code behind file:

```
        Control control = ControlHelper.GetControlById(mobilePage, "testLabel");
        if (control is Label)
        {
            Label testTekst = control as Label;
            testTekst.Text = "This is the tekst that comes in the label";
        }
```

Thanks for all of your help and suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you have access to the source, one easy way to correct this is have MobilePage inherit from the Panel class.  Panel is a container control that can take children (which also allows you to directly refer to them by name).